# jquery: run function on newly appended elements

Tags: jquery

The setup:

I'm using masonry along with infinite scroll, I'm also using a plugin called jQuery adaptive backgrounds, which extracts the dominant colour of an image and applies it to the images background.

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var $container = $('#container');
    // initialize
    $container.masonry({
        "isFitWidth": true,
        "columnWidth": ".item-post",
        itemSelector: '.block'
    });
    var $container = $('#container');
    $container.infinitescroll({
        navSelector: '#nav-below', // selector for the paged navigation
        nextSelector: '#nav-below a.next', // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
        itemSelector: '.block', // selector for all items you'll retrieve
        loading: {
            finishedMsg: "<div class=\"loading\">Fin.</div>",
            img: 'http://passets-ak.pinterest.com/webapp/style/app/common/images/spinner-medium-1x.34fc0f10.gif',
            msgText: "<div class=\"loading\">Loading the next set of posts...</div>",
            speed: 'fast'
    },
    },
            function(newElements) {
                var $newElems = $(newElements).css({
                    opacity: 0
                });
                $newElems.imagesLoaded(function() {
                    $newElems.animate({
                        opacity: 1
                    });
                    $container.masonry('appended', $newElems);
                });
            });
});
```

Adaptive backgrounds is called with  $.adaptiveBackground.run(); now I could just stick that inside function (newElements); and it'd call it each time new posts are loaded. 
The problem with that is that it's very inefficient (noticeably so) because it runs it on every element, even the ones it's already done it on.

My question is how do I run $.adaptiveBackground.run(); only on elements newly appended to #container and not the ones that are already there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://github.com/briangonzalez/jquery.adaptive-backgrounds.js)

> The script looks for image(s) with the `data-adaptive-background` attribute...

So that tells me you should do this:

```
$.adaptiveBackground.run();
$("img[data-adaptive-background]").removeAttr("data-adaptive-background");
```

...every time you run it. So the first run (on page load) will do the ones present in the markup, and then remove the attribute so they don't get re-processed. Subsequent runs (from your callback) will only process new ones (and then remove the attribute from them).

But the documentation *also* says that you can specify your own selector in an options object you pass into `run`:

> `selector` String (default: `'img[data-adaptive-background="1"]'`) a CSS selector which denotes which images to grab/process. Ideally, this selector would start with `img`, to ensure we only grab and try to process actual images.

...so that means you could also flag the new images with a marker class, tell adaptiveBackground to only process those, then remove the marker class. But it's the same concept.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in the reply. This is a great answer, T.J, thanks for the explanation too. Just one question, how would I run some other function after newElements fires?

Comment: @andy: Glad that helped. I'm not quite following you, the function I think you mean is a callback accepting `newElements` as an argument. To run something else, just add it to that function.

Comment: Yeah I mean when `newElements` fires, fire another named function that's defined outside the scope of the original function.

Comment: @andy: `newElements` is a function argument, it doesn't "fire." If you mean when the function that accepts that argument is called, you just put a call to your named function inside that function accepting `newElements`: `yourNamedFunction();` or whatever.